# Quickest way to find a duplicate in a array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was asked in an interview, what is the shortest or quickest way to find a duplicate in a array of **n** elements which could be either integers or floats. Though on searching in stack overflow, there are solution in particular with python usage, but if I wanted to implement the same in some programming language such as C or C++, what algorithm can I use or is there any way I could do it in O(N)?

Comment: Fastest way I can think is to make one pass, throwing each element onto a heap, and checking for dups as you go.  This would be N*log(N)

Comment: A duplicate or all duplicates?

Comment: one... but I want to how to do it for all...

Comment: Should 2 and 2.0 be a duplicate?

Comment: no... 2 and 2.0 should not be a duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

Though it might not be the most space-efficient algorithm, you can use a hashmap to store every value (key) you have encountered while traversing the array.  Then for each step along your array, you will perform an O(1) lookup in your hash table to see if you have seen this value before.  This solution is O(N) because you traverse the array of size N only once, and at each step you do a O(1) hash lookup.

Here is a method in C++ which implements this:

```
#include <map>

bool hasDupicate(int* input, int size) {
  std::map<int, int> m;
  for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (m.find(input[i]) != m.end()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // record the element you just saw in the map
      m.insert(std::pair<int, int>(input[i], 1));
    }
  }

  // could not find any duplicate
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Most languages support also a HashSet data structure. Also, as a small detail the amortized O(1) lookup assumes that the elements are hashed into the buckets "well". Most APIs allow to give an initial size / size estimate to make sure lookup is O(1).

Comment: @Tim will the program take long time to store given array again in a hashmap?

Comment: And now, as an experiment, try comparing the performance of this map-based check with simple implementation that just:
a) sorts the array in place
b) checks for adjacent elements that are equal
In many, many cases the overhead of creating elements of the hash map (especially for std::map which is really an RB tree) will dominate the cost and simple sort and check (even though asymptotically worse) will have better performance.

Comment: Even if there are no duplicates, requiring all N elements of your array to be inserted into a hashmap, the whole thing should still be O(N).

Comment: Krystian, could you give your in-place sort and O(N) walk as a full-fledged answer?  It would be good to have mulitple ideas here.

Answer (score 1):

Since Tim asked about a solution with sorting, here it is

```
bool hasDuplicate(std::vector<int> & input)
{
    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    return std::adjacent_find(input.begin(), input.end()) != input.end();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A { 2, 4, 9, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1 };
    std::cout << hasDuplicate(A) ? "has duplicates" : "no duplicates";
    return 0;
}
```

It has time complexity O(n log n) and reorders elements of the input sequence, but requires no extra memory allocations, so in many practical cases it may be faster than the asymptotically faster O(n) algorithm using hash tables given above by Tim.